# Control my Transmission GTK remotely

Tags: webserver, remote-access, bittorrent, transmission, remote-control

While I'm not home I left Transmission running, usually at full speed.  I've been mostly using the desktop gui (GTK) version.

I have been toying with the cli version (not sure which is the proper one between `transmission-cli` and `transmission-remote-cli`), and the web version (`transmission-daemon`), but my idea, rather than starting new downloads, is to control the downloads I have already running.

I am using my home computer also as a file and web server, and I want to be able to check if a torrent has already finished, or I have wanted to pause, change priorities or control the bandwidth **for those downloads still in the GTK** when I am away.

Is there a way, either Web (prefered) or CLI, that will allow me to control desktop downloads with Transmission when I am away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transmission GTK has a web interface.

In menu: **Edit** > **Preferences**, the **Web** tab, allows to enable web, and configure port, authentication and accepted incoming IP addresses.  That web interface controls the same torrents that are governed by the GTK.

I am not sure if the Web tab is available without having installed `transmission-deamon`, though.

Comment: It is. All the transmission clients have the web interface builtin. After enabling the web interface, you can also control the gtk client using `transmission-qt`, `transmission-remote` or one of the [third-party rpc clients](http://www.transmissionbt.com/resources/).

Comment: You can do almost anything with transmission-cli & transmission-remote. Here is an example: [Transmission shutdown script for multiple torrents](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202537/transmission-shutdown-script-for-multiple-torrents/343408#343408).